# How can I resize sda1 using Unallocted space

Tags: linux, gparted

Image of file system https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z20g.jpg

I am trying to increase the size of the partition sda1. But when I try to resize, I don't see any available space though I have 7GB of space. How can I increase the size of sda1 using either 5GB or 2GB unallocated space?

FYI I am using Gparted livecd
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitions you want to resize must be adjacent to unallocated space in order for the resize to work. I don't think you can move unallocated space, so you would need to move the sda1 partition next to the unallocated partition.

Unfortunately, since sda1 is the boot sector you will likely not be able to boot after you do this. You certainly can do this, but you will need to repair the boot sector, which is another issue (see http://gparted.sourceforge.net/faq.php#faq-6).

Also, the 5.59GB unallocated space is within an extended(logical) partition, so if you want to add that space to sda1, you will need to resize the sda2 extended partition to be 5.59GB smaller.